# How to draw a stroke on a half of a circle on top of the layout and the layout itself?

Tags: android

I want to achieve this row design. Its a cardview or a Relativelayout that has a circle and the whole design has a stroke.

[image]

Anyhelp?

EDIT:
the stroke is more clear here:
[image: stroke]

Answer (score 1):

It can be both `RelativeLayout` or `CardView`. There is no "halfcircle" it is usual circle with same color. You just align circle image view above layout that beneath and play a little bit with margins.

Comment: What about the stroke?

Comment: what stroke? what do you call stroke?

Comment: the gray line around the layout and the circle

Comment: oh, I believe this achieved via xml drawable that is put as background to both layouts

Comment: the stroke will cover the whole circle!

Comment: no, if you align it correct in Z axis. First you add the background circle, then the cardView and then the image. So the cardView will close the bottom half of the background circle but the whole image will appear at foreground